# Knapsack con GA

Tags: c++, revisión-de-código

Buenas,
Estoy trabajando en este algoritmo bastante sencillo que intenta solucionar el problema de knapsack con un algoritmo genetico. Me he basado en lo que he podido aprender de internet y el algoritmo compila y funciona, pero siempre me da 0 y la verdad no entiendo por que....
Alguien me podria echar una mano? 
Gracias

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

vector<double> weight;
vector<string> population;
vector<double> fitness;
bool run = false;


vector<double> make_prob(int n) {

    weight.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        weight[i] = rand() * 50;
    }

    return weight;
}


string makeGene(int n) {

    string g = "";


    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
        g = g + to_string(rand() % 2);
    }
    return g;

}



vector<string> makepop(int p, int n) {
    population.resize(p);
    for (int i = 0; i<p; i++) {
        population[i] = makeGene(n);
    }

    return population;
}

double evaluation(string g, vector<double> w, double max, int n) {
    double tw = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i<n; i++) {
        if (g[i] == '1')
            tw = tw + w[i];

    }
    double e = 0;
    double d = max - tw;
    if (d >= 0)
        e = tw / max * 100;

    return e;


}

vector<double> evalPop(vector<string> pop, vector<double> w, double max, int p, int n) {

    vector<double> fit(n);

    for (int i = 0; i<p; i++) {
        fit[i] = evaluation(pop[i], w, max, n);
    }
    return fit;
}

int select(vector<double> fitness) {
    double totalFit = 0, r = 0, sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<fitness.size();j++) {
        totalFit += fitness[j];
    }

    r = rand() * totalFit;

    do {
        sum += fitness[i];
        i++;
    } while (sum<r);

    return --i;
}

string cross(string n1, string n2, int n) {

    int c = rand() % n;
    return n1.substr(0, c) + n2.substr(c,(n2.size()-c)-1);

}

void breed(vector<string> population, vector<double> fitness, int p, int n) {

    vector<string> breedPop(p);

    for (int i = 0;i<p;i++) {
        int j = select(fitness);
        breedPop[i] = population[j];
    }

    for (int i = 0;i<p-1;i++) {
        population[i] = cross(breedPop[i], breedPop[i + 1], n);
    }

    population[p - 1] = cross(breedPop[0], breedPop[p - 1], n);

}

void printPopStats(int gen, vector<double> fitness) {

    double max = 0, totalFit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<fitness.size();i++) {
        if (max<fitness[i])max = fitness[i];
        totalFit += fitness[i];
    }
    cout << "Generation: " << gen << endl;
    cout << "Max fit: " << max << " Total Fitness: " << totalFit << endl;
}


int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    double max = 250.00 + rand()%50 * 500;
    int n = rand();
    weight = make_prob(n);
    int p = 20;
    population = makepop(p, n);
    int gen = 1;
    run = true;
    do {
        fitness = evalPop(population, weight, max, p, n);
        printPopStats(gen, fitness);
        gen++;
        breed(population, fitness, p, n);
        system("pause");

    } while (run);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para el que no sabe que es *knapsack* puedes poner la descripción del problema, el resultado esperado, etc etc

Comment: Solucionado. Me olvide de pasar la poblacion por parametro, y el valor nunca cambiaba, por eso siempre me daba el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no he podido mirarlo en ideone.com porque no compilar, pero en esta funcion:

```
double evaluation(string g, vector<double> w, double max, int n) {
    double tw = 0;

    for (int i = 0;i<n; i++) {
        if (g[i] == '1')
            tw = tw + w[i];

    }
    double e = 0;
    double d = max - tw;
    if (d >= 0)
        e = tw / max * 100;

    return e;
}
```

si esto es positivo `double d = max - tw;` se aplica `e = tw / max * 100;` donde `e` tiende a `0`.

si esto es negativo `double d = max - tw;` , `e` es `0`.

puedes iterar sobre `fitness[i]` y ver su contenido , entoces `if (max<fitness[i])` si max aqui es `0` aplicado a fitness[i] pues, max es 0

---

si cambia a `double d = max + tw;` es posible que no le muestre los `0` pero no se si ese es el comportamiento que espera.

P.D: Puede que tenga que revisar que los accesos a las direcciones de un los array esten dentro del rango, por ejemplo aqui `vector<double> fit(n);`

Comment: perdon por tardar tanto, estuve liado. por partes double d = max - tw; d es diferencia entre el peso maximo permitido y tw(peso total en la bolsa) es decir, si el d es negativo, la bolsa tiene sobre peso y entonces el gen(cadena binaria) no nos serviria, habria que cambiarla. El problema es que siempre me da 0. Intente cambiar el tamaño de la muestra y la longitud del gen y ya me da valores, pero siempre el mismo.....

Comment: PD: Investigando mas a fondo solo me queda una opcion posible. La funcion breed no hace bien la mutacion y siempre tengo los mismo genes, por eso siempre saco los mismo valores.....